# How to Draw custom Shapes using Bezier Curves in a Flutter CustomPainter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to draw the picture below using the flutter customPainter library with quadratic Bezier. How can I draw this shape?

[image: Required output image]

**My code**:

```
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.white;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill; // Change this to fill

    final path = Path();

    path.moveTo(-5, size.height / 2);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width / 2,
      -50,
      size.width + 5,
      size.height / 2,
    );
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

[image: my code output image]

Comment: You can try the tool [shape maker](https://shapemaker.web.app/#/). Here's the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnKgtKxRLX4).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Somehow I managed to get with this.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late , but this might benefit someone in the future .
what you are trying to do is creating 3 curves _ tow are concave and the meddle  one is convex. but in your code you have just one curve ,to solve this add two more quadraticBezier **I use Kotlin the "f" after each number is for Float value I don't know if it is the same in dart but you can figure it out** :

```
    final path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0f,0f);
    path.lineTo(0f,size.height);


    path.quadraticBezierTo(0f,4f/5f*size.height,size.width/4f,3f/5f*size.height)
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0.3f * size.width,0.5f * size.height,size.width/4f,2f/5f*size.height)
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0f ,1f/5f*size.height,0f,0f)
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

[image]